# How to edit a global footer link

Tags: globals

In the footer at the bottom of my page, [www.soldierswish.org](http://www.soldierswish.org), there are two links for `501c3` and `Form 990`. Is there no way to edit these from the GUI? How do I edit these links?

Comment: It heavily depends on how the site was build. We can't really say without knowing your structure. I think you are an editor and not the developer so you should contact the team/person/company who made the site. There are many different ways how it could be achieved. Can you somehow find an entry or an asset with those attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Look under Globals in the Control Panel, which is the likely place for such links. If you do not see it, either you do not have permissions OR there are no Globals. Assuming you do not see them, Robin's suggestion about contacting the developer is the next step.